# flask production and development mode

Tags: python, flask, config, development-environment, production-environment

I have developed an application with flask, and I want to publish it for production, but I do not know how to make a separation between the production and development environment (database and code), have you documents to help me or  code.
I specify in the config.py file the two environment but I do not know how to do with.

```
class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    """
    Development configurations
    """
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
    ASSETS_DEBUG = True
    DATABASE = 'teamprojet_db'
    print('THIS APP IS IN DEBUG MODE. YOU SHOULD NOT SEE THIS IN PRODUCTION.')


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    """
    Production configurations
    """
    DEBUG = False
    DATABASE = 'teamprojet_prod_db'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add onto Daniel's answer:

[Flask has a page in its documentation that discusses this very issue.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/config/)

Since you've specified your configuration in classes, you would load your configuration with `app.config.from_object('configmodule.ProductionConfig')`

Comment: The answer is 3years old and the current best option is to use `FLASK_ENV` config. Link here : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#environment-and-debug-features

Comment: @AdityaShaw not quite, it is still in the documentation here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#development-production

"best option" is an opinion, but this is still a valid approach.

Comment: @jesse-h without checking the environment variable, how can you know which config to load? (My first comment is wrong. I didn't mean to say it is wrong/old. The Daniel's answer is the right step to perform to know which mode you're in, imo.)

Comment: I like this answer, however, it looks there might be conflicts with some configs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840211/how-to-use-flask-env-inside-configuration-objects

Answer (score 39):

One convention used is to specify an environment variable before starting your application.

For example

```
$ ENV=prod; python run.py
```

In your app, you check the value of that environment variable to determine which config to use. In your case:

`run.py`

```
import os
if os.environ['ENV'] == 'prod':
    config = ProductionConfig()
else:
    config = DevelopmentConfig()
```

It is also worth noting that the statement

```
print('THIS APP IS IN DEBUG MODE. YOU SHOULD NOT SEE THIS IN PRODUCTION.')
```

prints no matter which `ENV` you set since the interpreter executes all the code in the class definitions before running the rest of the script.

Comment: Of course I specify the environment before the execution, but what I want is when I modify in dev. environment  I do not want the prod either touch, even if i restart my server (as if it is two different directory).