# How to use `FLASK_ENV` inside configuration objects?

Tags: python, flask

Following the examples for [Development / Production](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#development-production) from Flask documentation. Is not possible to use `FLASK_ENV` to configure flask environment?

```py
>>> class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
...     FLASK_ENV = "development"
...     DEBUG = True
... 
>>> class ProductionConfig(Config):
...     FLASK_ENV = "production"
...     DEBUG = False
... 
>>> def create_app(config="ProductionConfig"):
...     app = Flask(__name__)
...     app.config.from_object(f"{__name__}.{config}")
...     return app
... 
>>> app = create_app("DevelopmentConfig")  # I CREATE AN APP USING DevelopmentConfig
>>> app.run()
 * Serving Flask app '__main__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production  # WHY IS ENVIRONMENT SET TO PRODUCTION?
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can set `ENV` and `DEBUG` from the `settings` it may not work as expected and is not recommended.

> In order to set the environment and debug mode reliably, Flask uses environment variables.

For your reference, [Environment and Debug Features](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#environment-and-debug-features)

Answer (score -1):

So I finded out, although externally you should use `FLASK_ENV` internally you should just use `ENV`.

```py
>>> class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
...     ENV = "development"  # USE ENV INSTEAD OF FLASK_ENV
...     DEBUG = True
... 
>>> class ProductionConfig(Config):
...     ENV = "production"  # USE ENV INSTEAD OF FLASK_ENV
...     DEBUG = False
... 
>>> def create_app(config=ProductionConfig):
...     app = Flask(__name__)
...     app.config.from_object(config)
...     return app
... 
>>> app = create_app(DevelopmentConfig)
>>> app.run()
 * Serving Flask app '__main__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development  # NOW IS SET CORRECLY
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```